# How to use squid access logs to find frequency of web requests

Tags: frequency, squid

I am trying to build a model for how frequently users make web requests. I am interested in the timing between each new page they visit.  I want to build a load simulator which then uses this model.

To do this I've been analyzing Squid access logs and looking at the timing between http requests by user IP.  Squid captures all the requests associated with a web site request and I am only interested in the top level page requests. There are numerous starting pages for a request eg. not just *.html so it seems challenging to only capture the starting page for each session.

Is there a way to only capture the initial request for the top level page, like for when a user a page on Amazon, and then they jump to another page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Squid Analysis Report Generator it will read log files and generate reports in HTML format with detailed information like access and denied website,daily and weekly report.

Comment: OK  I have installed that tool (thanks for the tip), but it does not appear to do what I need.  I need to have the time "between" top level page acceses - not individual stats on each page which is loaded.  So I am trying to determine how often users enter new pages for browsing - hence am getting at their activity factor.    Are there any tools for this?